# What does "fixed_len_byte_array" mean?

Tags: parquet

I'm using the parquet file. I've found that parquet file has multiple data types, such as `int64,int32,boolean,binary,float,double,int96 and fixed_len_byte_array`.

I know `int64,int32,int96,boolean,binary,float and double`. But I can't understand `‘fixed_len_byte_array’`.

> What does "fixed_len_byte_array" mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a normal byte array, only it's size is prefixed for better or worse, you cant change it.

You can see example of usage in

https://github.com/apache/parquet-format/blob/master/LogicalTypes.md

Comment: Thank you very much. That's just what I need

Comment: Googling is never the answer. Now, 1st link in google is this question